# select a list of interfaces with Python CISCOCONFPARSE and regex

Tags: python, regex, ciscoconfparse

I use a double loop to select all interfaces GigabitEthernet1/0/1 to 1/0/16 and 2/0/1 to 2/0/16 using efficient tool CISCOCONFPARSE : here is the example, that works :

```
CONFIG_PARSED = CiscoConfParse(CONFIG)
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(1,17):
        INT = CONFIG_PARSED.find_objects('^interface GigabitEthernet'+str(i)+'/0/'+str(j)+'$')
```

Question :
Is there a way to do the same using a simple loop with a regex such as my incorrect example below ?

```
for INT in CONFIG_PARSED.find_objects('^interface GigabitEthernet[1-2]/0/[1-16]$')
```

This other example below is a valid regex, but does not allow to select 1 to 16 numbers :

for INT in CONFIG_PARSED.find_objects('^interface GigabitEthernet[1-2]/0/')

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have two options...

**OPTION A:** Parse port numbers yourself, using stable and supported CiscoConfParse code...

```
import re
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

CONFIG_PARSED = CiscoConfParse(CONFIG)
intf_rgx = re.compile(r'interface GigabitEthernet(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)$')
for obj in CONFIG_PARSED.find_objects('^interface GigabitEthernet'):
    mm = intf_rgx.search(obj.text))
    card = int(mm.group(1))
    port = int(mm.group(3))
    if card>2:
        continue
    if port>16:
        continue
    ## Do something here with obj
```

**OPTION B:** Offload port number parsing to CiscoConfParse's alpha-quality (as of version 1.1.5) port number parser...

```
import re
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

CONFIG_PARSED = CiscoConfParse(CONFIG, factory=True)
for obj in CONFIG_PARSED.find_objects('^interface GigabitEthernet'):
    card = obj.ordinal_list[0]
    port = obj.ordinal_list[-1]
    if card>2:
        continue
    if port>16:
        continue
    ## Do something here with obj
```

FYI, `obj.ordinal_list` returns a python list of integers representing the card, slot and port number of the interface.  For instance `ordinal_list` for "GigabitEthernet2/0/11" is `[2, 0, 11]`.  You must use version 1.1.5 (or higher) and parse with `factory=True` to get `ordinal_list`.

---

**DON'T DO THIS**:

The example you provided is truly bad from a performance perspective, because `find_objects()` walks the entire Cisco IOS configuration, start to finish looking for the regex provided.  In case it isn't obvious, walking the entire Cisco IOS configuration 32 different times with `find_objects()` is very slow.

```
CONFIG_PARSED = CiscoConfParse(CONFIG)
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(1,17):
        INT = CONFIG_PARSED.find_objects('^interface GigabitEthernet'+str(i)+'/0/'+str(j)+'$')
```